# SimpleHTML Loop returning Undefined Index

Tags: php

I had used SIMPLE HTML DOM to capture three different elements. And I want to display it one by one. However it shows me an error message on using for loop:

> Undefined index: i.

What's the matter? Please help me.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://....');

$a=$html->find('div.briefimage');
echo $a[0];

$b = $html->find('span.briefcitTitle');
echo $b[15];
$c = $html->find('table.bibItems td');
echo $c[0]; 

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
    echo $a[i]->plaintext . '<br>';
    echo $b[i]->outertext . '<br>';
    for ($j = i; $i <= 2; $j++) {
    echo $c[i]->innertext . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before iterating through the lop check whether every array is set.Or try using `isset` to check whther array is set.Also print_r() or var_dumb your array to check whether you are getting values in array.You are getting the notice because one of your array doesnt contain values.

Answer (score 1):

Your should be using `$i` instead of just `i` ... so change

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
    echo $a[i]->plaintext . '<br>';
    echo $b[i]->outertext . '<br>';
    for ($j = i; $i <= 2; $j++) {
    echo $c[i]->innertext . '<br>';
    }
}
```

to

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
    echo $a[$i]->plaintext . '<br>';
    echo $b[$i]->outertext . '<br>';
    for ($j = $i; $i <= 2; $j++) {
       echo $c[$i]->innertext . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that one of your arrays `$a`, `$b` or `$c` is missing the key you're trying to access with `$i`:

```
$foo = array('a', 'b');
$i = 3;
echo $foo[$i]; # Error because there is no third key in $foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taken a quick look, try `$i++` rather than `++$i`

If that doesn't work var_dump $a, $b & $c